# Syntax error for inet parse_address command in elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-shell

I am new to [elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/). My task to check if the given `string` is an `ip address or a number`. I found that [inet](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#parse_address-1) has this `parse_address` which checks if the given string is an ip address or not and provides the appropriate response.

My code on the iex terminal is as follows

```
inet :parse_address("192.168.42.2")
```

When I run the above code on the terminal I get the following error

```
 iex(1)> inet :parse_address("192.168.42.2").
 ** (SyntaxError) iex:1: syntax error before: '('
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
:inet.parse_address('192.168.42.2')
```

because module names are just atoms but in erlang, they start with a lowercase letter.

There is a lot of articles covering the subject on Erlang interoperability, one of those is here -> https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/erlang/

Comment: I think it should be `:inet.parse_address('192.168.42.2')`. String with " is giving `{:error, :einval}`. Curious why that's the case!

Comment: @kiddorails Apparently the function expect erlang strings, which are charlists in elixir.